# R maximum likelihood algorithm

Tags: r, time-series

I have to build a maximum likelihood estimator from scratch, no built-in mle function allowed.
I am maximizing a random variable but not w.r.t. the mean or the variance, I have another parameter (the beta from a moving average (1) process).
so here is the code I have built, but it tells me that the "optimize" function cannot find the initial values. I have the observations in a matrix. Rows are different observations, the columns are different simulations (that is why I have a loop at the beginning, running from 1 to R=10000).
Help MUCH appreciated :)

```
for (i in 1:R) {
llh_regr <- function (β, y, z) {
  kappa <- -((N-1)*log(pi*2)+(N-1)*log(1))/2
  residuals <- (y-c-β*z)
  loglik <- kappa-(1/2)*crossprod(residuals, residuals)
  return(loglik)
                               }

targetfunction <- function(β) {
  return(-llh_regr(β, y = x[,1], z = u_lag[,1]))
         }
  B[1,i] <- optim(runif(1), targetfunction)
}
```

Comment: *no built-in mle function allowed* - is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Copy the source code from `stats4::mle`, change the variable names, and hope nobody catches you :-).  Seriously-what's the point of writing an estimator "from scratch" if you're allowed to use packaged "optimizer" code?

Comment: It is a project I have to do, and it is not for an R class bur for a time series one. It appears that it is actually a common exercise for R users in finance to do such calculations. I am not even studying finance so you can imagine how happy this makes me...